# Expected value of sum of two gaussian random variables conditional on their difference

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Given two standard normally distributed random variables $x_1$ and $x_2$. $y = x_1 + x_2$

I would now like to calculate the following:

$$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[y | x_1 -x_2 = 0]$$

My idea was to do it as follows:

$$\int y \frac{P(y=x_1 + x_2, x_1=x_2)}{P(x_1=x_2)}$$

But the probability that $x_1 = x_2$ should be $0$. Therefore, this does not seem to be the right approach. Where is the mistake in my thinking?

Comment: The sum and difference are uncorrelated, as is easy to see by computing their covariance.  **Assuming $(x_1,x_2)$ are _jointly_ Gaussian,** this implies the sum and difference are independent and so you don't even have to worry about the conditioning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are IID $\mathop{\mathcal{N}}\left(0,1\right)$, and $Y=X_1+X_2$, then

\begin{align}
\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left[Y|X_1-X_2=0\right] &= \mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left[X_1+X_2|X_1-X_2=0\right]\\
&= 2\cdot\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left[X_1\right]\\
&= 0\\
\end{align}

Comment: Can you explain the second last step in more detail? I don't understand how you get $2 * \mathop{\mathbb{E}} (x_1)$.

Comment: When $X_1=X_2$, what is $X_1+X_2$?

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting question in terms of approach. Two general advices: To untangle, it often helps to be rigorous in one's notation. You have an integral without proper notation: The limits are often omitted when they are defined by the variable, but you have also omitted with respect to what variable the integral is taken (the $dx$ or the $dy$). The other is to go back to the definitions, as I do below:

For your specific question:
Write $Y = X_1+X_2$ and $Z = X_1-X_2$. You now have the joint pdf $f_{Y,Z}(y,z)$ and the marginal pdfs $f_Y(y)$ and $f_Z(z)$. The conditional pdf of $Y$ given $Z$ is then
$$
  f_{Y|Z}(y|z) = \frac{f_{Y,Z}(y,z)}{f_Z(z)},
$$
for any $z$ such that $f_Z(z)> 0$.

As pointed out in the comment, the $P(X_1=x_2)$ in your question does not correspond to $f_Z(z)$, as the former relates to the CDF and the latter is the pdf.

Comment: Assuming you're using $f_Z$ to represent the PDF of $Z$ rather than the CDF, what makes you say that $\mathop{f_Z}\left(0\right)=0$?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Here I assume that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. You didn`t say so, but it was probably implied. Then they have a binormal distribution, so correlation zero implies independence.

Define $Y=X_1 + X_2$, $Z=X_1 - X_2$. $Y$ and $Z$ does also have a binormal distribution, and since their correlation is zero (a simple exercise), they are independent. So conditioning on $Z$ does not bring any new information.
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}  
  \E\{ Y \mid Z=0\} = \E Y = 0
$$